# When set proxy, facebook opens slowly

Tags: facebook, selenium, proxy, webdriver

When I use proxy, my, several web pages (etc. facebook) loads very slowly. This is script:

> ```
> import random import time
>
>  import os import sys from selenium import webdriver
>
>  chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
>
>  os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
>
>  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from
>  selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys from
>  selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select from
>  selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException from
>  selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException import
>  unittest from time import gmtime, strftime from datetime import
>  datetime from random import randint
>
>
>  PROXY = "114.77.67.32:22" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
>
>  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>  chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)
>
>  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
>  driver.get("http://web.facebook.com")
> ```

Is it good method to visit pages with another IP ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `-trustAllSSLCertificates` parameter when launching Webdriver? It helped with this [resolved problem](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3020).

Otherwise you should try some other proxy or connect to launch tests from another host, there's no other simple way around this.